# join 3 tables very complicated in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join

```
 i have 3 tables (employee,structure,District)

 1_employee table contains  empid,workid  and actuallwork  fks to structid 
 2_ structure table contains structid , districtId fk to district
 3_District table contains districtid , districtname
```

i want to get

```
empid  ,  work
```

,  actuallwork (disitrict name  from foreign key actulalwork)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same table multiple times in a query providing you gave distinct alias to each occurrence. Structure and district are listed twice, first time as work/district, second time as actualwork/actualdistrict. This is how you differentiate where columns come from when dealing with multiple references to the same table.

```
select employee.empid,
       district.districtname,
       actualdistrict.districtname acturaldistrictname
  from employee
    inner join structure work
       on employee.workid = work.structid
    inner join district
       on work.districtfk = district.districtid
    inner join structure actualwork
       on employee.actuallworkfk = actualwork.structid
    inner join district actualdistrict
       on actualwork.districtfk = actualdistrict.districtid
```